Button goes to specific section on page XD
I am wanting to create an interaction for each of the sub sections of 'Our Products' button so when you click on lets say Produce it will go to the 'Our Products' page but navigate to the section thats specifically produce.
I basically want to do the same thing as this tutorial except have that navigate to another page.
video tutorial
https://xd.adobe.com/view/c3e284c3-495c-4caf-9f40-cdd96c714cbb-96b1/[![enter image description here]2]2

